# hiding multiple movie clips

Tags: actionscript-3, movieclip

i'm following this tutorial http://workflowflash.com/3901/hiding-movie-clips-in-as3.php for hide and show movie clips, but i want to hide and show multiple movie clips using one button.

i'm making a simple animation(movie clips) with bubbles text(movie clip). so i want to hide all bubble text when i click disable dialog button.  - hide movie clips inside a movie clip. should i use array?

i'm really new to this, so i hope someone can help me and i really appreciate it. :)

Answer (score 1):

Sure, you can use array, but is it a best way - it depends on many things.

Maybe try something like that:

```
var myArray:Array = [myMoveclip1, myMoveclip2, myMoveclip3];

switchBtn.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, _switch);

private function _switch(e:MouseEvent) : void {
    for each(var item:MovieClip in myArray) {
        item.visible = !item.visible; // or just "item.visible = false;" to only hide
    }
}
```

Now your button will be hiding and showing MovieClips from array, but I'm not sure if that is what you expect/need.

Comment: thanks @Lukasz! but i've got a new error.

Error #1099: Cannot access a property or method of a null object references at Main/disableDialog()

is that mean flash can't find my movie clips(bubble text). is it because bubble text inside movie clips?

Comment: var myArray:Array = [myMoveclip1.mcInside, myMoveclip2.mcInside1, myMoveclip2.mcInside2]; That is how you can access mclips inside other mclips